# cannot display mat-table content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

What is the expected behavior?

display the content without an error
an example of data :

```
[{…}] 0: dateReport:"2019-05-12" flgVise:true pctPointeAgence:1 
title:"title2" __proto__:Object length:1 __proto__:Array(0)
```

What is the current behavior?

i get this exception

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined
    at StickyStyler.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.StickyStyler._removeStickyStyle (table.es5.js:900)
    at StickyStyler.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.StickyStyler.clearStickyPositioning (table.es5.js:721)
    at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable.updateStickyHeaderRowStyles (table.es5.js:1669)
    at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable._forceRenderHeaderRows (table.es5.js:1986)
    at MatTable.push../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js.CdkTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.es5.js:1370)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:9258)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:9236)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:9226)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10157)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10394)`

What is the use-case or motivation for changing an existing behavior?

component typescript:

```
export class ListeEtatComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
displayedColumns = ['title', 'dateReport', 'pctPointeAgence', 'flgVise'];
DATA_SOURCE = new MatTableDataSource();

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

reports: Report[];
constructor(private etatInterneService: EtatInterneService) { }
ngOnInit() {

}
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.fillTable();
}
fillTable(): void {
  this.etatInterneService.getReports().subscribe(
    (reports: Report[]) => {
      this.DATA_SOURCE.data = reports;
      console.log(reports);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
}

}
```

and my html is :

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="DATA_SOURCE" matSort>
  <!-- Etat interne  Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Etat interne </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let report">
        {{report.title}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!--  Date report Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="dateReport">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Date report </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let report">
        {{report.dateReport}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- % Pointé  Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="pctPointeAgence">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> % Pointé </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let report">
        {{report.pctPointeAgence}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Visé Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="flgVise">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Visé </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let report">
      <mat-radio-button color="warn" [checked]="report.flgVise" disabled></mat-radio-button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
    <tr class="tableSecondHeader">
      <th colspan="1">clés fixes</th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">indicateur en table"entéte des etats interne"</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr mat-header-row></tr>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" ></tr>
</table>
```

Which versions of Angular, Material, TypeScript, browsers ?

@angular/cdk: 6.2.1

@angular/material: 6.2.1

@angular/core: 6.0.5

typescript: "2.7.2"

browser: chrome

**update :**
it work when i move fillTable to ngoOnInit() but i think the problem remain in the multiple header rows :

it work with

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
```

but not with :

```
<ng-container *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
<tr class="tableSecondHeader">
  <th colspan="1">clés fixes</th>
  <th></th>
  <th colspan="2">indicateur en table"entéte des etats interne"</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr mat-header-row></tr>
```

**UPDATE**

it worked now

i used this example for multiple header rows

[table-multiple-header-footer](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-multiple-header-footer/table-multiple-header-footer-example.html)

Comment: You should place fillTable() inside your ngOnInit() if you are fetching the dataSource from a server

Comment: i did and it work if i remove the multiple header rows, but still got an error with the mulitple header rows

Comment: If you provide the json you receive or a part of it maybe I can reproduce the error and help you

Comment: Did you copy-paste that from github?

Comment: *<ng-container *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">* this wont work as `matHederRowDef` must be placed on html element, not on virtual container.